# Delete data from two tables with INNER JOIN

Tags: php, sql, inner-join

I want to delete data from two tables with one SQL query according to `datetime_lastactive` and if the IP addresses is matching your own. But I'm getting this error message when I try out the following SQL query:

`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INNER JOIN visitors_main WHERE information_ipaddress = '123.123.123.123' A' at line 2' in ...`

```
DELETE FROM visitors_list
INNER JOIN visitors_main
WHERE information_ipaddress = :ipaddress
AND datetime_lastactive < NOW() - INTERVAL 3 HOUR
```

The tables looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `visitors_list` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_visitor` int(10) DEFAULT '0',
  `id_user` int(10) DEFAULT '0',
  `data_filename` text NOT NULL,
  `data_filename_get` text NOT NULL,
  `data_useragent` text NOT NULL,
  `datetime_lastactive` datetime NOT NULL,
  `information_ipaddress` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `visitors_main` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_user` int(10) DEFAULT '0',
  `data_coordinates` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `datetime_firstvisit` datetime NOT NULL,
  `checkbox_anonymous` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
  `checkbox_tiecoordinates` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
  `checkbox_nogps` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
  `information_ipaddress` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
)
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: Try using back ticks for table names.

Comment: Thanks but that didn't solve the problem. I got the same error message

Comment: Use a ON condition before WHERE.

Comment: @Mihai `... ON information_ipaddress = :ipaddress WHERE ...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
DELETE l, m
FROM visitors_list AS l
INNER JOIN visitors_main AS m ON l.information_ipaddress = m.information_ipaddress
WHERE l.information_ipaddress = :ipaddress
AND l.datetime_lastactive < NOW() - INTERVAL 3 HOUR;
```

Comment: Thanks! But I'm only getting `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'information_ipaddress' in where clause is ambiguous' in ...`. Why `DELETE visitors_list`? I don't want to delete the entire table. Just the data in it (and also in visitors_main)

Comment: @ErikEdgren - This is because of the foreign key constraint between the two table, you can make it `CASCADE DELETE` to delete from the other table as well. But do you want to delete from the two tables or from only one of them?

Comment: I want to delete the data with the same IP address from both tables.

Comment: @ErikEdgren - OK Sorry, then change the join condition to be on that column `information_ipaddress` then all the matched columns from both of the tables will be deleted.

Comment: Thanks but I keep getting the same error message - `Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'information_ipaddress' in where clause is ambiguous'` :/ `CASCADE DELETE visitors_list FROM visitors_list ...` doesn't work either; `Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CASCADE DELETE visitors_list FROM visitors_list INNER JOIN visitors_main ON vi' at line 1'`

Comment: @ErikEdgren - Try to coalify it like this `vistiors_list.information_ipaddress` instead. See my edit.

Comment: The same error message -.- `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'vistiors_list.information_ipaddress' in 'where clause'' in ...`

Comment: @ErikEdgren Sorry, it is a typo, It should be `visitors_list` instead of `vistiors_list`.

Comment: Thanks! My head ain't clear today so I though you meant the typo :P Your SQL query deletes the old data from `visitors_list` but not from `visitors_main`. I have tried to add `, visitors_main` after `DELETE visitors_list` but it didn't help :/

Comment: @ErikEdgren - Sorry for late. I am on work now  :( but this is what it said in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html): `For the multiple-table syntax, DELETE deletes from each tbl_name the rows that satisfy the conditions`

Comment: @ErikEdgren - Try to use aliases like `DELETE l, m
FROM visitors_list as l
INNER JOIN visitors_main AS m ON l.information_ipaddress = m.information_ipaddress` it working fine [**see it here in action**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/76a46/1) It is deleting from both the tables.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE v1,v2
FROM visitors_list v1
INNER JOIN visitors_main v2 ON v1.id_visitor = v2.id
WHERE v1.information_ipaddress = :ipaddress
AND v1.datetime_lastactive < NOW() - INTERVAL 3 HOUR;
```

Comment: `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'visitors_list.information_ipaddress' in 'where clause'' in ...`